# generate Web.config for loading data from a file to MS SQL 2008 server database in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I am working on C# on Win 7 Visual Studio 2012.

I need to load data from a txt file to a database (MicroSoft SQL server 2008).
The data file is located on my local laptop drive. It is not on the same server as database.

Currently, the database has many tables. I need to create a new data table.

I think I need to generate a Web.config file, right ?

I am new to these.

I find some answers here:

```
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8x4ket8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
```

But, it is VS 2008 not 2012. It is not helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No; that has nothing to do with it.  Learn about Entity Framework.

Comment: SQL server can already import txt files, why not use that?

Comment: @RedFilter, I need to load data from a txt file in a C# program to datatbase.

Answer (score 0):

Your file needs to be on an specific format to be readable; by specific format I mean CSV(comma separated) for instance.

If the above condition is meet:

SQL Server has something called bulk insert that you can use to import files content into a table. However, the file needs to be on same server as the database. 
 Or you can code a file reader and manually insert each record in database.

Normally database configurations are on safe place, if you added to your app.config you probably will want to encrypt it.

Comment: the data file is located on my local laptop drive. It is not on the the same server as database.